# Android calling a fragment with arguments clicking on a listview inside a custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, adapter, android-adapter

i've a MainActivity extending FragmentActivity that calls some fragments with a navigation drawer, one of these fragments shows a listview created by a custom adapter i did, my question, how can i call another fragment by clicking a single textview of this listview passing an id or a String related with that element? i saw interface as communication between fragmnets but in my case i can't manage the click event inside the fragment because i do in the adapter. sorry for bad english (very bad english)

FragmentOne

```
package com.example.ghisa;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {   
     public String testo;       
     public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        FragmentOne f = new FragmentOne();


        return f;
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle     savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, null);

        //nei fragment non possiamo fare getApplicationContext() ma getActivity che ritorna
        //l'attività associata al frammento l'attività è un context dal momento che activity extends context

       Database db=new Database(getActivity());        
         db.open();  //apriamo il db  

         List list = new LinkedList();

         Cursor c = db.prendiSchede();
         /* Check if our result was valid. */ 
   if (c != null) {//Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "asdasd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   c.moveToFirst();
   int firstNameColumn = c.getColumnIndex("nome"); 
   int id=c.getColumnIndex("id");
   if (c.isFirst()) { 
       int i = 0; 

       do { 
            i++; 
            String firstName = c.getString(firstNameColumn); 
            int id1=c.getInt(id);

            list.add(new Scheda(firstName,id1)); 
       } while (c.moveToNext()); 
  } 
   }


// Caricamento dati nella listview e nell'adapter tramite results
     (getActivity(),R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.ListView2,results);
         final ListView listView= (ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.listView);     
         final AdapterSchede adapter1 = new AdapterSchede(getActivity(),  R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

       listView.setAdapter(adapter1);

  final TextView text=(TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.ListView3);


       Button button2 = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.inviascheda);
       button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

           Database db=new Database(getActivity());        
              db.open();  //apriamo il db   
              EditText text = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.creascheda);
               String testo=text.getText().toString();
               if(testo!=null){
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scheda creata!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  db.inserisciScheda(testo);

                  android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                  ft.replace(R.id.main, new FragmentOne()); //yesss 
                  ft.commit();
              }

         }
       });



      return root;

    }

    }
```

my custom adapter

```
package com.example.ghisa;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AdapterSchede extends ArrayAdapter<Scheda>{
public static List f;
public static int posizioneid;

    public AdapterSchede(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
             List list ) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
         f=list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
             .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
        TextView nome = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListView3);
        Button b1= (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancellascheda);

        final Scheda s = getItem(position);
        //qua mette nella TextView nome il nome preso dall'item s
        nome.setText(s.getNome() +" "+ s.getId());
        final int idd=s.getId();


        nome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // HERE I SHOULD CALL ANOTHER FRAGMENT PASSING THE FIELD nome 

}


            }
            });


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Toast.makeText(getContext()," "+ idd, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Database db=new Database(getContext());        
                 db.open();
                 db.cancellaScheda(idd);
                 f.remove(position);
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
            }       
            });

        return convertView;
    }

  public  void setid(int pos){
        final Scheda k;
        k = getItem(pos);
        setposizionelemento(k.getId());
    }

  void setposizionelemento(int idd){
      this.posizioneid= idd;

  }
}
```

THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 3):

Replace fragment from your adapter like this :

```
TARGET_FRAGMENT tf = new TARGET_FRAGMENT ();
tf.setArguments(YOUR_ARGUMENT_BUNDLE);

FragmentTransaction ft = YOUR_CONTEXT.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ft.replace(R.id.container_layout, tf);
 ft.addToBackStack(null);
 ft.commit();
```

Now get argument in target fragment like this :

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {

         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
             //here is your arguments
             Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 

            //here is your list array 
            String[] myStrings=bundle.getStringArray("tag");   
         }
    }
```

**UPDATE : GET CONTEXT**

```
private FragmentActivity mContext;

 public AdapterSchede(FragmentActivity context, int textViewResourceId, List list ) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
         this.mContext = context;
         f=list;
    }
```

Now you can use `mContext` at the place of `context`

Comment: Thank for the fast answer :) what should i put in YOUR_CONTEXT, i began studying android a week ago thank you!

Comment: if you are in activity use ClassName.this, or in fragment use getActivity().

Comment: yes, i said that before because using getActivity i get The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: Use the context which is in your Adapters constructor. Check my updated answer.

Comment: On private  mContext; i get Syntax error on token "private", import expected :D

Comment: Sorry I't was my mistake. I updated my answer. You have to write private Context mContext;

Comment: i was trying before you answer to do private Context mContext;
and i get" Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"
:(

Comment: the code is above, in the class AdapterSchede i'm trying to write Context mContext; and i get" Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens" thank you

Comment: now it says The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Context

Comment: Try to replace getFragmentManager() with getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Context :( the class is    AdapterSchede extends ArrayAdapter<Scheda>

Comment: Check my updated answer. Replace Context with FragmentActivity.

Comment: and now... The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, FragmentTwo)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new YourFragment()).
                            addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved by passing to the adapter as variable also the fragmentmanager

```
   FragmentManager fragmanager = getFragmentManager();

       final AdapterSchede adapter1 = new AdapterSchede(getActivity(), R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, fragmanager);
```

and then in the adapter i can the fragment transaction method!

Answer (score 0):

Getting fragMentManager from context in the adapter won't work. Get it from the fragment calling the adapter and pass it to the adapter via its constructor.